# Print raw Dialogflow query result fulfillment message

Tags: flutter, dart, dialogflow-es

I have the following DialogFlow default and Facebook responses for an intent.
[image: default response]
[image: facebook response]

I have a simple Flutter app that calls detectIntent on a DialogflowAPI object that returns a response with query result. I want to print the raw fulfilment messages to console.

```
...
    var response = await df.detectIntent(request, sessionPath);

List<GoogleCloudDialogflowV2IntentMessage> payloads = response.queryResult.fulfillmentMessages;
debugPrint("Got response length: ${payloads.length}");
payloads.forEach((element) => debugPrint(element.payload.toString()));
```

I get the below console output:

```
flutter: Got response length: 3
flutter: {text: this is some default text!, replies: [default option 1, default option 2]}
flutter: null
flutter: {replies: [default option 1, default option 2], text: this is some default text!}
```

There are 3 responses, of which 2 are printed correctly. It does not print the quick replies part of the facebook response.

Answer (score 0):

Each `GoogleCloudDialogflowV2IntentMessage` has a `payload` member, which is a json-like `Map<String, Object?>`. You can print this out:

```dart
payloads.forEach((element) => debugPrint(element.payload.toString()));
```

---

### Alternatively

There is also a `toJson()` method, which might give you more complete information. You can try printing that as well:

```dart
payloads.forEach((element) => debugPrint(jsonEncode(element.toJson())));
```

**Note:** you'll need to include `import 'dart:convert';`.

Comment: That will not compile. Error: The argument type 'Map<String, Object>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String?. It worked when I added toString() on the payload, but partially. I've modified my original question.

Comment: Sorry about that - I rarely use `debugPrint` and assumed it took a dynamic argument, like `print`.